# How to implement memoization in dart?

Tags: dart, memoization

> Hi Everyone, I am new to dart, I tried to implement memoization but it is not working, please tell me how to implement memoization.
> Thanks in advance.

```
int memoizedFibonacci(n,{memo:null}) {
  if(memo == null){
    memo = Map();
  }
  if(memo.containsKey(n)){
    return memo[n];
  }else{
    memo[n] = memoizedFibonacci(n-1, memo:memo) + memoizedFibonacci(n-2, memo: memo);
  }
  return memo[n];
}
main() {
  print(memoizedFibonacci(10));
}
```

> Error:
> Unhandled exception:
> Stack Overflow
> #0      int.hashCode (dart:core-patch/integers.dart:541:3)
> #1      _OperatorEqualsAndHashCode._hashCode (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:149:25)
> #2      _LinkedHashMapMixin._getValueOrData (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:355:26)
> #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.containsKey (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:375:54)

Comment: Your recursive call has no base case, so it recurses forever.  If you initialize `memo` as `memo = {0: 0, 1: 1};`, then it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Now I got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memoization is a concept. You can store it wherever you want, in my example below, I store it in my Fibonacci List, and take it from there.

```
  int val = 7;
  List<int> fib = [0, 1];
  DateTime start = DateTime.now();
  for (int i = fib.length; i <= val; i++) {
    fib.add(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
  }
  // [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```